# Package not generated from endpointscfg

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to generate an Android client lib from my Python endpoints API by running endpointscfg.py

endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -o . -f rest services.MyApi

The problem I have is that a none-.*-sources.jar is generated, and the client classes are created under a Java package named "none.MyApi".

How can I override the generated package name to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients). Try specifying the `hostname` either as a flag to `endpointscfg.py` when invoked from command line:

```
endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java \
> --hostname=some-client-id.appspot.com \ 
> services.MyApi
```

or in your API definition:

```
@endpoints.api(name='apiname', version='version',
               hostname='some-client-id.appspot.com',
               ...)
```